# flask_sqlalchemy not creating model classes in database with import statement

Tags: python, sqlite, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to create a set of tables from model classes using flask_sqlalchemy.

If the model classes are defined inline within the install.py, then the tables are correctly created from model classes. However, if I import model classes from original python classes, it is giving error.

**Working code**

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash
import uuid

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:////Users/suryasingh/Documents/code/python/api/model/api.db'

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Todo(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    text = db.Column(db.String(50))
    complete = db.Column(db.Boolean)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer)

db.create_all()
db.session.commit()
```

**Not working:** If I replace model class inline code with import statements

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash
import uuid

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:////Users/suryasingh/Documents/code/python/api/model/api.db'

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

from model.todo import Todo

db.create_all()
db.session.commit()
```

**todo.py:** model class

```
from model.dbmaster import db

class Todo(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    text = db.Column(db.String(50))
    complete = db.Column(db.Boolean)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer)
```

**Error**

```
api suryasingh$ python3 install.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/suryasingh/Software/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/_collections.py", line 1020, in __call__
    return self.registry[key]
KeyError: <greenlet.greenlet object at 0x7fce90af7930>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "install.py", line 53, in <module>
    main()
  File "install.py", line 50, in main
    create_admin()
  File "install.py", line 37, in create_admin
    db.session.add(new_user)
  File "/Users/suryasingh/Software/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/scoping.py", line 163, in do
    return getattr(self.registry(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/suryasingh/Software/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/_collections.py", line 1022, in __call__
    return self.registry.setdefault(key, self.createfunc())
  File "/Users/suryasingh/Software/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 3300, in __call__
    return self.class_(**local_kw)
  File "/Users/suryasingh/Software/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 174, in __init__
    self.app = app = db.get_app()
  File "/Users/suryasingh/Software/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 1042, in get_app
    raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: No application found. Either work inside a view function or push an application context. See http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/contexts/.
```